# One time each one

Tags: sql

I have build my database ofcourse etc but I have problem with the code.I try to solve that 
"Names of marines(one time each one) that have for reservation red boat and their have tonnage bigger than 200." and I did that.

```
Select distinct m.name
From marina m join reservation r on (m.mid, r.mid)
Where r.bid = (select b.bid from boat b where b.color = "red")
```

I tryed use that https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ but I failed so I post here if someone can help edited.That is my database.

```
drop table if exists reservation;
drop table if exists marina;
drop table if exists boat;
drop table if exists sailor;

create table boat
    (bid integer not null constraint c_bid primary key,
     bname varchar(40),
     color varchar(40) 
     constraint c_color check (color in ('Red','Blue','Light Green','Yellow')));


create table marina
    (mid integer not null constraint m_key primary key,
     name varchar(40) not null,
    capacity integer);

create table sailor 
    (sid integer not null constraint c_sid primary key,
     sname varchar(40),
     rating integer 
     constraint c_rating check (rating between 1 and 10),
     age real constraint    
     c_age check (age < 18 OR age = 18));


create table reservation
    (sid integer not null constraint f_key1 references sailor(sid) on delete cascade,
    bid integer not null constraint f_key2 references boat(bid) on delete restrict
                                   constraint c_bid check (bid not in (999)),
    mid integer constraint f_key3 references marina(mid) on delete set null, 
    r_date date not null constraint c_date check (r_date > '02/04/1998'), 
    constraint p_key primary key(sid,bid,r_date));


INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (2, 'John', 6, 17);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (11, 'Mary', 10, 18);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (12, 'TH', 7, 14);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (13, 'John', 9, 18);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (1, 'Christin', 10, 17);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (15, 'Thod', 10, 13);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (16, 'Leonid', 5, 13);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,age) VALUES (17,'Left',17);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (19,'Polu',1,16);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (27,'Marinin',8,15);
INSERT INTO sailor(sid,sname,rating,age) VALUES (37,'Cos',8,14);


INSERT INTO marina(mid,name,capacity) VALUES(33,'Porto',300);
INSERT INTO marina(mid,name,capacity) VALUES(5,'Calam',105);
INSERT INTO marina(mid,name,capacity) VALUES(1,'Plat',32);
INSERT INTO marina(mid,name,capacity) VALUES(7,'Pos',19);
INSERT INTO marina(mid,name,capacity) VALUES(2,'Our',105);


INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(88,'Sof','Blue');
INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(17,'Ag','Light Green');
INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(13,'Panag','Yellow');
INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(1,'Αg.N','Red');
INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(72,'Christin','Red');
INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(19,'Dil','Light Green');
INSERT INTO boat(bid,bname,color) VALUES(77,'Αg.G','Blue');


INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(2,88,7,'1999-02-17');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(12,17,2,'1998-05-17');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(11,17,2,'1999-01-17');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(13,13,7,'2003-01-13');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(11,13,33,'2000-05-05');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,1,33,'2000-05-05');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,13,33,'2000-05-06');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,17,33,'2000-05-07');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,19,33,'2000-05-08');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,72,33,'2000-05-09');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,88,33,'2000-05-10');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(1,77,2,'2000-08-10');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(19,13,33,'1999-10-12');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(27,88,7,'2000-06-11');
INSERT INTO reservation(sid,bid,mid,r_date) VALUES(37,72,2,'2001-04-27');
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't manage it to edited as you want.I post the code to the site but nothing.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I don't know ..it asks me also and bigger than 200 and that I didn't put it too

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with an EXISTS sub-query:

```
select m.*
from marina m
where m.capacity > 200
  and exists (select *
              from reservation r
                 join boat b on r.bid = b.bid
              where mid = m.mid
                and b.color = 'Red')
```

`where m.capacity > 200` only selects marinas with a capacity that is bigger than 200 (this is how I understand the "*have tonnage bigger than 200*")

The (co-related) sub-query then checks for reservations for each marina that were made for a red boat (that's how I understand the "*that have for reservation red boat*" part).

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b36f7e79b90d9c77400d3b0194846a8d)